# How to insert values if some is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
FirstName     LastName     University
   Bob         Brown        Aviation
   Kate        Dylan        Economic
   Tommy       Loren        Aviation
```

University have default value : **Aviation** .
Have stored procedure where insert values to table,
in procedure call have 3 parametres :

```
@declare firstname varchar(50),
@declate lastname varchar(50),
@declare university varchar(50)

insert into myTbl (FirstName,LastName,University) values(@firstname,@lastname,@university)
```

I want if in procedure @university is empty dont insert into table for example if i exec :
`EXEC myProcedure 'Joseph','Divan',''`   it must insert into table only **firstname and last name** university will be Aviation because it is default value

Comment: In the procedure, set `null` as default value for `university` parameter. Then check if that parameter is null. If so use this: `insert into myTbl (FirstName,LastName) values(@firstname,@lastname)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your default name of "University" column will always be **Aviation**, I would suggest this approach.

Set a default value constraint for "University" column, if the value is null it will automatically insert the default value.

```
ALTER TABLE myTbl ADD CONSTRAINT DF_UName DEFAULT N'Aviation' FOR University
```

and then use this code

```
declare @firstname varchar(50),
declate @lastname varchar(50),
declare @university varchar(50)

IF (@university = '' OR (@university IS NULL) )
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO myTbl (FirstName,LastName) 
        VALUES (@firstname,@lastname);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO myTbl (FirstName,LastName,University) 
       VALUES (@firstname,@lastname,@university);
END
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No, this will not work. The default column value will not be used if you explicitly insert null into the column. If you don't specify the column in the insert statement, the column's default value will be used. Your suggested code will either insert null into the table, or cause an error if the column does not allow nulls.

Comment: oh, you are right, it wont take the default value if we specify it explicitly. corrected  my answer.

Comment: Now it looks good. The only mystery is why it was accepted before the edit. We will never know I guess! :-)

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL allows you to set default value for parameters in stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc 
    @firstName varchar(50), 
    @lastName varchar (50), 
    @university varchar(50) = 'Aviation'
AS
INSERT INTO myTbl (FirstName,LastName,University) 
    VALUES (@firstname,@lastname,@university);
```

You can use it in two ways:

```
EXEC MyProc 'Bob', 'Brown'
EXEC MyProc 'Kate', 'Dylan', 'Economic'
```

Comment: This will work, but if the table definition changes so that a different default value needs to be used, then you must remember to also change the default value in this procedure.

Comment: @user1429080, thanks, useful remark. On the other hand, one must simply choose how to store default value: as a constraint or as a value for procedure. It depends on requirements, but in both cases it's necessary to keep it updated.

Comment: Yes. My comment was based on the assumption that the default was set on the column specification for the table. But since the accepted answers suggest a method that would not work in those cirumstances, it seems my assumption was incorrect. I still don't see how the accepted answer could possibly work unless the default value is maintained by some trigger or other esoteric workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better for you to change the table schema for better performance.

You can alter table schema as shown below to incorporate Default value.

```
ALTER TABLE myTbl
ALTER COLUMN Univesity SET DEFAULT 'Aviation'
```

P.S. If you need to go with Stored Procedure only, then you can refer above answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@declare firstname varchar(50),
@declate lastname varchar(50),
@declare university varchar(50)

IF (@university is not null)
BEGIN
    insert into myTbl (FirstName,LastName,University) values(@firstname,@lastname,@university)
END
```

Comment: I need if it-is null or empty just skip , not print something

Comment: Try now i have modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just put the following before the insert into statement:

if @university is null set @university = null

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you choose to check whether the University is blank or not, try to extract the IF condition out of the stored procedure as it slows down the execution and consumes memory for execution plan. The best would be to use the IF condition in query and call two different stored procedures depending on fulfillment of the condition

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include a parameter check when you are inserting the values. If you havent specified any Value it will set 'Aviation' as default

```
insert into #MyTbl (FirstName,LastName,University) values(@firstname,@lastname,isnull(@university, 'Aviation'))
```

Thanks